# The width of img before appending to DOM?

Tags: javascript, image, dom, download, width

I've done some simple code tasks and I've found that I can get height and width of downloaded img by its img.height and img.width attributes, without appending it to DOM. Is this crossbrowser? Coudn't find any info on this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` for that requirement. They represent the **original** width and height respectively of the image.

`naturalWidth` - the original width of the image used in tag.

`width` - the value/default value of width attribute of tag.

`naturalHeight` - the original height of the image used in tag.

`height` - the value/default value of height attribute of tag.

For example:

```js
let src = 'http://www.fillmurray.com/g/400/600';
let img = document.createElement('img');
img.onload = () => {
  console.log(`naturalWidth = ${img.naturalWidth}`);
  console.log(`naturalHeight = ${img.naturalHeight }`);
}
img.src = src;
```

More about `naturalHeight` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/naturalHeight

More about `naturalWidth` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/naturalWidth

Comment: is this crossbrowser, I mean, can I get naturalWidth after img downloads without appending to dom?, like "img.src = 'blabla'; img.onload = () => img.naturalWidth"

Comment: Yes, please check out my example above. I'm not appending anything to the dom. just downloading a file and logging it's dimensions once it's loaded.